# Foundation 5 dropdown not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, zurb-foundation

This is my HTML: https://gist.github.com/ojanorg/eca87332de4ad28749e0

This i my CSS-file: https://gist.github.com/ojanorg/ecedccfd422bd597a3e2

I am learning Foundation 5 atm and I am building a page that has a dropdown.
I have studied the documentation and the code I have come up with is in the gists.

As of now I have no idea why the dropdown isn't working as expected.

I am doing this inside a rails view. If that helps.

Everything is at the most current version.

Comment: Have you added `$(document).foundation()` to your javascript? It should be at placed at the bottom of your layout as inline script.

Comment: In what javascript file do you mean? Because in the application.js file I have this line: $(function(){ $(document).foundation(); }); added by the Foundation installer for Rails.

Comment: I added the line you specified, and I get the same error as before: TypeError: Undefined is not a function(evaluating: $(document).foundation()). The bells that rings for me is that Foundation isn't installed properly. I used gem 'Foundation' rails g install:Foundation.

Comment: Hmmm, interesting. Try open JS console and type `Foundation`. Do you have `//= require foundation` in your application.js?

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem after digging through the console.

In my application.js I had //= require_tree . that made my app include foundation three times.

That made it not working as intended. So I removed that line and now everything is working as intended.

Thanks all for your input!